# Make inner div width dynamic

Tags: html, css, width

I want to give remaining width to **.inner** div. At the Same time it's siblings (a & span tags) can be of dynamic width.

Any idea?
Code below & at https://jsfiddle.net/pge8rqw0/

```css
.top {} .inner {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
}
a {
  float: left;
}
span {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <span>Html is good</span>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: `<a>` and `<span>` width is known??

Comment: no they are also content dependent.

Comment: @Piyuesh Can you change order of your elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using `display: flex`.

```css
.top {
  display: flex;
}
.inner {
  border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 50px;
  flex: 1;
}
a {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
span {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <span>Html is good</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution works fine. But I was trying to use it in altering wkhtmltopdf's TOC (http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt), & sadly it was not supporting flex. Thanks............

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the order of elements in your code then you can achieve it without `flex` as follows:

```css
.top {overflow: hidden;}
a {
  float: left;
}
span {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
}
.inner {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
  <span>Html is good</span>
  <div class="inner">Inner Content</div>
</div>
```